# Who was telling the truth about Arthur-Penny-Thomas? Penny or Thomas?

Tags: plot-explanation, joker

In the movie Joker (2019), we see Penny claiming Arthur to be Thomas' son. We have Thomas refuting these claims as well.

We later learn that Penny was in an abusive relation and that she suffered mentally and physically. It seems like she was deluded about the father of Arthur. It could really have all been in her head.

It could also simply be Thomas covering his tracks and planting those records against Penny, which is really not a big task for a man of Thomas' stature.

Given all this, who was telling the truth about this whole scenario (Arthur's father)? I did watch the movie till the end and didn't miss any scenes but I was clueless who was telling the truth and I don't think this was addressed.

Comment: The whole movie is full of red herrings, uses the unreliable narrator device, entire sections might be figments of imagination,... The point is that there are no definite answers, IMHO.

Comment: i agree,,,  takes away the essence truly !! i really wished that wasn't the case !

Comment: @Anu7 True, but that is how one would essentially come to feel like the character--Being left in an unsettling place where one feels contempt for not knowing what is real and what is only in your head. Is the joke on them or is it on oneself???? :/

Comment: The Joker is a character whose origins are officially unknown as per the "usual" comic history - this way they can keep to that while still exploring the descent into madness of the character

Comment: Don't the newspaper cuttings/psychiatric documents confirm that Arthur was Penny's adopted son?

Comment: @Mr_Thyroid i know.. but it could have been easily planted by Thomas back then and the newspapers reported what was planned and executed by Thomas. So my question was that.. who was right ?

Comment: @DarthLocke beautifully said! I can accept this confusion :) .. Thank You !!

Comment: @Anu7 Yes it is possible, but as far as I remember, this possibility was never mentioned in the film.  I think that given how explicit the film was about the relationship with his neighbour, how we were left in no doubt that it was a delusion, if the film wanted us to believe that it was still possible that Thomas was his father, it would have mentioned it.

Comment: I took it that Arthur really was TW's son (remember this is pre-DNA era...). It is utterly implausible that an unmarried woman with addiction problems would be allowed to adopt - even in the 80s! Of course, that leads to the obvious conclusion about sibling rivalry...

Answer (score 1):

https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2019/10/joker-mom-movie-penny-fleck

> But one day Arthur reads one of her letters before sending it out for
>   her, and it’s revealed that she’s asking Thomas for help because
>   Arthur is their son, a product of an affair they had all those years
>   ago.
>
> It’s such a big twist that it instantly seems impossible to maintain.
>   After all these years this movie is trying to tell us that Joker and
>   Batman were half brothers? (“The whole time? The whole time?”) Of all
>   the twists in this movie, this one is the most unbelievable. Sure,
>   comic book movies have to take big swings and occasionally shake up
>   the canon to keep viewers engrossed, but a change like this would add
>   unnecessarily meaningful dimension to the Batman–Joker rivalry. The
>   film, however, plays it straight and presents this revelation as fact,
>   asking viewers to just go along with it...even though Joker’s
>   mom-and-son duo are deluded pipe dreamers who harbor absurd fantasies.